# Spring Boot @Autowired não funciona com o repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, injeção-de-dependência, repository

Tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Description:

Field categoriaRepository in 
com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.resource.CategoriaResource 
required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Código da classe principal do projeto:

```
package com.algaworks.algamoneyapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AlgamoneyApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AlgamoneyApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Código da Entidade:

```
package com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long codigo;
    private String nome;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Categoria categoria = (Categoria) o;
        return Objects.equals(codigo, categoria.codigo);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(codigo);
    }
}
```

Código do Repository:

```
package com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.repository;

import com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.model.Categoria;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface CategoriaRepository extends JpaRepository<Categoria, Long> {
}
```

Código do Controller:

```
package com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.resource;

import com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.model.Categoria;
import com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.repository.CategoriaRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/categorias")
public class CategoriaResource {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository;


    @GetMapping
    public List<Categoria> listar() {
        return categoriaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.algaworks</groupId>
    <artifactId>algamoney-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>algamoney-api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Estrutura do projeto:

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Já tentei:

- `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.algaworks.algamoney.repository")`
- `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.algaworks")`
- `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.algaworks"})`

mas nada funciona.

Comment: Olá, não é certeza mas experimente trocar a anotação `@Autowired` por `@Repository` e remover esta última da declaração da interface `CategoriaRepository`. Acho que a anotação `@Repository` deve ser aplicada a variáveis não-locais, já subentende a `@Autowired`, e produz (instancia) uma implementação default de repositório para qualquer variável do tipo `JpaRepository` ou do de alguma sub-interface da mesma. Será que chutei certo?

Comment: Vamos ver se eu entendi corretamente:
Trocar na CategoriaResource a anotação @Autowired por @Repository? Porém dá erro de sintaxe: ```@Repository' not applicable to field```.

Acredito sim ser correto sobre instanciar a implementação de um repository quem diz para que o spring faça isso é a anotação ```@Autowired```.

Comment: Você está certa, eu me enganei. Não entendo muito de Spring. `@Repository` subentende `@Component` e não `@Autowired`. Entendi o que quis dizer com erro de sintaxe, mas creio que o erro é semântico.

Comment: Sim, semântico! kk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o repositório não está sendo carregado no contexto do Spring. Para fazer isso, é utilizada a anotação `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Existem algumas formas de se fazer isso, acredito que no seu caso as mais simples são:

- Adicionar `@EnableJpaRepositories` em `AlgamoneyApiApplication`. Por convenção, o SpringBoot vai escanear todas as classes por `@Repository` ao iniciar sua aplicação, e vai incluí-la no contexto do Spring;
- A sua tentativa: de adicionar `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.repository")` em `AlgamoneyApiApplication`. Porém, repare no pacote: o seu repositório está em `com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.repository` e vc tentou com `com.algaworks.algamoney.repository`. Provavelmente por isso que não funcionou.

Comment: Também me pareceu estranho não funcionar sem necessidade de modificações adicionais, porque, pelo que sei, para fim de mapeamento de repositórios é escaneada toda a árvore de subdiretórios/subpackages a partir do que possui a classe anotada com `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Continurou dando erro, porém diferente agora. 

``` 
Description:

Field categoriaRepository in com.algaworks.algamoneyapi.resource.CategoriaResource required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53194', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @AlineAvila Se resolveu o primeiro problema, acho que é conveniente aceitar a resposta dada (e, quando tiver mais pontos, positivar). Aqui é um problema por vez (isto é, por pergunta). Vi que não fez o [tour], recomendo fazer.

Comment: @Piovezan resposta aceita.

Comment: @AlineAvila Agradeço se você puder acrescentar seu arquivo `pom.xml` à pergunta para torná-la reproduzível, foi falha minha não pedir. Aí para o seu próximo problema eu penso que para economizar copia-e-cola você pode linkar esta pergunta na nova que eventualmente for fazer.

Comment: @Piovezan pelo que eu entendi, não foi utilizado o `@EnableJpaRepositories` sem o `basePackages`, o erro foi que foi forçado um package errado

Answer (score -1):

Quando o model está na dependencia, é necessario colocar

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "teupacote })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "teupacote" })

junto como o @SpringBootApplication